# Incorrect syntax in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I've written an update stored procedure and here is the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE writer_update_art
    @articleid int
    @title nvarchar(50) ,
    @subject text ,
    @tag nvarchar(25),
AS
    update articles 
    set (title = @title, subject = @subject, tag = @tag) 
    where articleid = @articleid

    RETURN
```

but an error appears:

> Incorrect syntax near'@title'
>   Incorrect syntax near'('

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need brackets for `SET` syntax and you had misplaced commas:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE writer_update_art
    @articleid int,
    @title nvarchar(50),
    @subject text,
    @tag nvarchar(25)
AS
    update articles set title = @title , subject=@subject , tag=@tag 
    where articleid=@articleid
RETURN
```

Comment: actually I put the brackets in order to solve this problem !! but it didn't work

Comment: I noticed commas later as well. Commas where the source of your problem

Answer (score 2):

Don't require inner parentheses or extra comma at end of param list (and comma required after first param in list):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE writer_update_art
(
    @articleid int,
    @title nvarchar(50) ,
    @subject text ,
    @tag nvarchar(25)
)
AS
    update articles 
    set title = @title, 
        subject = @subject, 
        tag = @tag 
    where articleid = @articleid
RETURN
```

Comment: There's still one comma missing after `@articleid int`

Comment: didn't work ! ... and a new error saying : 'Must declare the scaler variable "@title". !

Comment: WoW thanx !! @Mitch Wheat .. IT WORKED !!!!! so strange  I still don't know where was the problem !

Comment: You still don't know what's wrong?? Despite their being 2 explanations?

Comment: yes ... because I always do what I wrote and this error never appeared before !

Comment: @user3126376: so thankful, you decided to unaccept my answer and accept a very late answer that was an obvious copy. Dodgy as.