# stored procedure shows an error for the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

while I'm trying to make an update stored procedure this error popup to me

> > error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from call to a com component

this is the sp :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE writer_update_art
@articleid int , 
@title nvarchar(50) ,
@subject text ,
@tag nvarchar(25) 
AS 
    update articles set title=@title , subject=@subject , tag=@tag
    where articleid=@articleid

    RETURN
```

I used to make sp in this way but this error never appeared before ! any help please ?

Comment: How do you call this SP, where from? You tagged the question as linq-to-sql, yet you're getting COM error. Also your code is missing `CREATE/ALTER` - is it copy/paste error?

Comment: well I dragged it into my Linq to sql calss then I call it as a method in my code !

Comment: Is it a WinForm/Console app? If so - can u delete your BIN and OBJ folders and try to rebuild thep project? If it's an ASP.NET project - try deleting "Temporary ASP.NET files" folder and rebuild it

Comment: I found a previous sp added to my sp folder in the db ( which I deleted it ) look at the 1st answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735635/incorrect-syntax-in-stored-procedure this is what the prev. sp look like !!

Comment: Temporary ASP.NET files is clean and clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the stored procedure and restart your server and your visual studio then code your sp again! this **may** help, because your sp doesn't have anything wrong